# Export data from a non-normalized database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, export

I need to export data from a **non-normalized database** where there are **multiple columns** to a new normalized database.
One example is the *Products* table, which has 30 boolean columns (ValidSize1, ValidSize2 ecc...) and every record has a foreign key which points to a *Sizes* table where there are 30 columns with the size codes (XS, S, M etc...). In order to take the valid sizes for a product I have to scan both tables and take the value SizeCodeX from the Sizes table only if ValidSizeX on the product is true. Something like this:

```
Products Table
--------------
ProductCode <PK>
Description
SizesTableCode <FK>
ValidSize1
ValidSize2
[...]
ValidSize30

Sizes Table
-----------
SizesTableCode <PK>
SizeCode1
SizeCode2
[...]
SizeCode30
```

For now I am using a "template" query which I repeat for 30 times:

```
SELECT
    Products.Code,
    Sizes.SizesTableCode, -- I need this code because different codes can have same size codes
    Sizes.Size_1
FROM Products
INNER JOIN Sizes
ON Sizes.SizesTableCode = Products.SizesTableCode
WHERE Sizes.Size_1 IS NOT NULL
AND Products.ValidSize_1 = 1
```

I am just putting this query inside a loop and I replace the "_1" with the loop index:

```
SET @counter = 1;
SET @max     = 30;
SET @sql     = '';

WHILE (@counter <= @max)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + ('[...]'); -- Here goes my query with dynamic indexes

    IF @counter < @max
        SET @sql = @sql + ' UNION ';
    
    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END

INSERT INTO DestDb.ProductsSizes EXEC(@sql); -- Insert statement
GO
```

Is there a better, cleaner or faster method to do this? I am using **SQL Server** and I can only use **SQL/TSQL**.

Comment: There's a rogue comma in your template query (end of line 4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that a "clean" (and much faster!) solution is the [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function.
I found a very good example here:

http://pratchev.blogspot.it/2009/02/unpivoting-multiple-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare a dynamic query using the SYS.Syscolumns table to get all value in row

```
DECLARE @SqlStmt                 Varchar(MAX)
 SET @SqlStmt=''
 SELECT @SqlStmt = @SqlStmt + 'SELECT '''+ name +''' column ,  UNION ALL ' 
 FROM SYS.Syscolumns WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
 WHERE Object_Id('dbo.Products')=Id AND ([Name] like 'SizeCode%' OR [Name] like  'ProductCode%')

  IF REVERSE(@SqlStmt) LIKE REVERSE('UNION ALL ') + '%'
    SET @SqlStmt = LEFT(@SqlStmt, LEN(@SqlStmt) - LEN('UNION ALL '))

   print ( @SqlStmt )
```

Comment: I just found a solution which doesn't use dynamic SQL and it's very fast!